# How do I get the phone numbers of my Facebook Friends?

Tags: facebook, contacts, phone-number

There was a time that somehow Facebook synced to my phone and that was great but I did not want all of them. How can I manually select the Facebook numbers and then export it to my phone via Contacts or Microsoft Exchange ? Where is this option ?

Comment: https://www.facebook.com/mobile/messenger/contacts/, you should see the  phone number there!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it possible that I could see the mobile number of Facebook friends](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/77783/is-it-possible-that-i-could-see-the-mobile-number-of-facebook-friends)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

On Facebook:

1. Click the "Account" dropdown menu.
2. Click "Edit Friends"
3. Look on the left-side menu for "Phonebook".

All friends with their phone numbers entered will appear in the list.

Comment: Additionally, there is no way to (politely) access this information in a nice format for use outside of Facebook, though there are many tools which hack this solution for you. 

http://www.google.com/search?q=how+to+export+facebook+phone+numbers

Comment: Thanks ! Is there a way to filter by friends list ? That way I can at least drop the set into a group

Comment: I don't believe there is. It's all or nothing for phone numbers. But maybe one of the tools in that google search would do the trick for you. Alternatively, if you use Android/PalmOS/(and iPhone?), Facebook integrates its phone numbers into your address book automagically.

Comment: This option is not available anymore.

Answer (score 1):

I use a service called MemoToo and you can [check out how I set it up on my blog](http://blog.hinshelwood.com/archive/2010/07/07/the-search-for-a-single-point-of-truth.aspx).

A much easyer way is to use a hosted service like MemoToo and you can [check out how I set it up on my blog](http://blog.hinshelwood.com/archive/2010/07/07/the-search-for-a-single-point-of-truth.aspx).

If you go to http://memotoo.com and setup an account you can have your contacts synced with tons of services including:

- Outlook
- Google Contacts
- Google Calander
- Facebook (One way)
- LinkedIn (One way)
- Windows Live Contacts
- Yahoo Contacts
- Twitter
- Windows Mobile
- Android
- Plaxo
- Soocial
- SheduleWorld
- UNYK
- Vodafone 360 (this is a realy crap service though)
- And tones more

Its also ver cheap and you only need to pay £12 per year if you have more than 50 contacts. I have 2000+ and it work just fine.

I did have a couple of hours of De-duping to do afterwords with so many services, but once you have sone that once all is good. Most dups can be deleted, but if you have a contact on Facebook and LinkedIn it is better to merge them.

This gets all of your Facebook contacts as long as they have given you access to their phone number. If they have not, then all you will have is their name. However you will probably find that your friends use some of the services listed above and you can sync all of them and get the most up to date details from all of your contacts wither they are just on facebook or anywhere else.