# Get a List of Facebook Friend's Email addresses

Tags: facebook

How can I get a list of email addresses of Facebook Friend's that have published their email address? My request is similar to the phonebook [question](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/33/how-do-i-get-the-phone-numbers-of-my-facebook-friends).

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I get the e-mail addresses of my Facebook friends?](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/129/how-do-i-get-the-e-mail-addresses-of-my-facebook-friends)

Comment: I've updated my question to be clearer. I want email addresses of Friend's that have published their email.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this but only for good.
Violating [Facebook Developer Terms of Service](http://developers.new.facebook.com/terms.php) results in a ban.

NO redos **nada**

Login to a registered Yahoo Mail account.

Click `Contacts` -> `Tools` -> `Import` -> `Facebook`

The you can keep it there and sync with the rest of your contacts or export as a .csv file.

Comment: Thanks pretty awesome, suprised yahoo beat google to the punch.