# How to get a list of the @facebook.com email addresses of my Friends

Tags: facebook

Predecessors

- [Get a List of Facebook Friend's Email addresses](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/1605/40)
- [How do I get the e-mail addresses of my Facebook friends?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/129/40)

So with the slow roll out of the new Facebook Messaging Platform, I was wondering how possible it would be to obtain these email addresses for use in my Gmail and iPhone contact list finally closing up on my [Phonebook question](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/33/40).

I read that these email addresses use the username you picked for your vanity url if you chose one. So facebook.com/boy should be boy@facebook.com. How would one be able to get these addresses (This question mainly goes out to those that already have the Messaging Platform enabled) ?

I am not worried about disabled/enabled addresses because I know that those that are not enabled are bounced back (Tried checking my own).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think this is possible .....yet.

This is [taken from the Developers section](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/message/) on Facebook. It appears that they are gradually releasing the API information regarding the new Messaging Platform and only to registered Developers.

> **Please note:** We are in the process of making the new messages system
>   available to all users, at which point
>   this API will replace the /inbox/
>   graph API endpoint. We are providing
>   early access to this API **for
>   registered developer accounts only**
>   until the new messaging system is
>   broadly available. You should use the
>   /inbox endpoint for production
>   applications at the current time.