# Is it possible that I could see the mobile number of Facebook friends

Tags: facebook, contacts, phone-number

Is it possible that I could see the mobile number of Facebook friends?
I saw the following post, but I did not find it because Facebook has changed.
[How do I get the phone numbers of my Facebook Friends?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/33/how-do-i-get-the-phone-numbers-of-my-facebook-friends)

Comment: I don't think closing as a duplicate of a question with outdated information does much good to anyone. @MichelfrancisBustillos  If anything, closing in the opposite direction makes sense.

Comment: If the question requires new answer, a bounty should be placed on it and/or it should be edited.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get phone number of your friends by going into

```
His/her profile->About->Personal information
```

there you can find his/her mobile number.

> If and only if he/she provided his mobile number and also only if it
>   is not secured it totally depends on his/her profile privacy settings.
>
> 1. If the privacy is set to "Public" no matter whoever you are you can
>          get that mobile number.
> 2. If is set to "Friends/Friends of Friends" then if you are direct
>          friend of his/her or at least if you have any mutual friends then you
>          can get the number.
> 3. If is set to "only me" then there is no way for you to get the number.

Answer (score 0):

The only option, is if they have shared to *Only Friends* of *Only Friends of Friends* or *Public* their phone mumbers. Privacy options in their accounts might intervent in this too.

But it it is the case, you'll able to watch it on *Information* tab on their FB Profile.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, you can see the mobile number if they keep it as *Friends of friends* and *Public only*. If they keep *Only to me* (privacy) you can't see the phone number, but you can call them in Facebook without knowing their number.